# Javascript action in onclick is not executed before reload page in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a button in my aspx page that when the user clicks, it executes an action and then reloads the page to see the changes reflected. That action, among other things, calls the server through WebService.

The process works fine in Chrome, but fails when using Firefox.

I have tried different options and none of them work in Firefox:

```
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.reload();"><i class="whatever"></i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.reload();return false;"><i class="whatever"></i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.assign('MyPage.aspx');"><i class="whatever"></i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.assign('MyPage.aspx');return false;"><i class="whatever"></i></a>
```

If I remove the page reload/assign command, it works fine in Firefox. But with reload or assign command, it just reloads the page without executing the action.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with your quotation in the html. The `"` inside `"` part.

Possible fix:

```html
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.reload();"><i class="whatever">icon</i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.reload();return false;"><i class="whatever">icon</i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.assign('MyPage.aspx');"><i class="whatever">icon</i></a>
<a id="myButton" class="button" title="The button" onclick="DoAction(this, 12345);window.location.assign('MyPage.aspx');return false;"><i class="whatever">icon</i></a>
```

Comment: This is not the problem. I'm sorry but it was my mistake when copying the examples. In the system there is no problem with the quotation marks. I have updated the examples. Anyway, thanks for your help.